# Does the infinite sequence of $\frac{(-1)^n}{n}+ 6$, Converges or Diverges?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Does the infinite sequence of $\frac{(-1)^n}{n}+ 6$, Converges or Diverges?

I know the term $\frac{(-1)^n}{n}$ from the alternating harmonic series, which always converges. But I add a constant and also I consider a  *sequence* not a *series.*

Answer (score 2):

I am little bit confused on whether you asked for the convergence of the series $\sum \left( \frac{(-1) ^n}{n} +6\right)$ or the convergence of $\sum\left( \frac{(-1) ^n}{n} \right) +6$ or just the sequence $\frac{(-1) ^n}{n} +6$, as you have mentioned both the terms series and sequence in your question.

In the first case it is divergent as $n$-th term of the sequence of partial sums increases by $6n$. In the second case it is convergent as the $n$-th partial sum increases by $6$ and $\sum \frac{(-1) ^n}{n}$ is convergent. Also in the third case it is convergent as it is sum of two convergent sequences.

*Note (quid): This refers to an earlier version of the post, but is mostly still relevant.*

Comment: OP is not concerned with series, but sequences.

Comment: @Allawonder True...but he mentioned the alternating harmonic **series** ......confusing

Comment: I added a note to avoid confusion, as the post was edited. Feel free to modify or remove via an [edit]

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

As, the sequence  $\frac{(-1)^n}{n} \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$ . Now, what can you say about the limit of the sequence $\frac{(-1)^n}{n}+ 6$?

Answer (score 0):

Your sequence is in the form of $b_n = (-1)^n/n + 6 = a_n + 6$. As you are adding a constant the limit is independent from it, i.e. $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} b_n = 6+\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} a_n$.

In a complete space, like the real numbers, a sequence converges if and only if it is a Cauchy sequence. So, it is a Cauchy sequence if $\forall \epsilon >0 \exists N\in \mathbb{N} \forall m,n \geq N : |b_m-b_n| = |a_m - a_n| < \epsilon$.